# Difference between Test Cycle and Test Suite, in qTest

Tags: manual-testing, test-management, qtest

I am trying to navigate qTest for the first time and get a good understanding of the application.

What is the difference between a Test Cycle and a Test Suite as described by qTest's Test Execution area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [this manual](https://support.qasymphony.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003290543-Add-Releases-Cycles-and-Test-Suites-in-Test-Execution):

**Test Cycle:**

> A test cycle is a container that shows a high-level summary of its underlying test runs, including the execution results of these tests and any defects found.  Within a given release, you may need to execute many types of tests.  For this reason, you may have more than one test cycle within the release or even multi-level Test Cycles, which will be beneficial for organizing and reporting.

**Test Suite:**

> A test suite can be regarded as the lowest level container to organize test runs.  Test suites provide more specific information about a given set of test executions.  It is here that you add test runs and specify the version of the test case that will be executed.  Test runs can be assigned and executed in bulk as well as individually (test run by test run).

So basically *Test Suite* is a container that you fill up with the tests. *Test Cycle* is the aggregation of *Test Suites* where you can pick aggregated statistics for the entire cycle.

Answer (score 0):

From my perspective ,

Test suite is a collection of related test case ,
for example , Test Suite for *`Check broken links in my web apps`* contains every test case for every links you want to check.

Test Cycle is a iteration of a Test Suite itself ,
for example you may do *`Check broken links in my web apps`* Test Suite till it pass , so you will have several Test Cycle for that Test Suite.
And so you maybe have several Test Suites in one Test Cycle.

Comment: I appreciate your perspective, but I am looking for the perspective from the Test Management application called qTest, so this doesn't really answer the question that I posed.

Answer (score -1):

Qtest is a test management software used by the small as well as large-scale software testing company. Below information may help to understand the difference between test cycle and test suite in q test:

**Test suite** is a collection of test cases for any individual feature or combined one. These test suites are part of the **test cycle**.

A **test cycle** are the execution results of test suites on different cycles. Each release can have multiple sprints or you can say that cycles. Test cycle gives you the summary or reports of the test execution in each cycles.Test cycle is always a part of Single release and is defined in the scope of the Test Release.